# what is the Context-Free Grammar for the following language?

Tags: context-free-grammar, regular-language, nsregularexpression, context-free-language, automata-theory

Here is the language and I want to create a context-free grammar for it:

```
b(bc+a)*a(a+b)*c*
```

Here is my answer but I don't know if it's right or not:

```
S → bAaB
A → bcA | aA | epsilon
B → cB | aB | epsilon
```

Comment: B rule doesn't look right.

Comment: Your A and B rules are  wrong. For instance your language should contain something like `bbcccccaa` but I can't see that happen in your grammar. But your grammar accepts for instance `baca` which is not contained in the language

Comment: @kiner_shah then how would that grammar accept a word like `bbccccaa`

Comment: @derpirscher, my bad, I forgot `+` means 1 or many. I thought it was bc OR a.

Comment: @kiner_shah Because of `b(bc+a)*a` (and everything after it being optional)? Ie `b` followed by `bc+a` followed by `a`

Comment: @kiner_shah might be a valid interpretation (although I don't remember seeing a `+` interpreted as OR anywhere outside boolean algebra). Then of course rule A would be correct, but B still be wrong

Comment: @derpirscher, yeah I don't know what made me think that.

Answer (score 0):

See the grammar below. It might be possible to simplify it a bit, but it should do the trick.

```
S -> bAaBC
A -> bcCaA | epsilon 
B -> aDbB | epsilon 
C -> cC | epsilon 
D -> aD | epsilon
```

The `A` rule allows one `b` followed by any number (but at least one) `c` followed by a single `a`. And this can occur any number of times (also zero)

The `B` rule allows any number (but at least one) of `a` followed by a single `b`. Again the whole expression can occur any number of times.

The `C` rule allows any number of `c`. This is used for the `c*` at the end of the word but also for the `c+` in the first part (ie it's used in rule `A`)

The `D` rule allows any number of `a`. It's just a helper in rule `B` to accept the `a+` in the second part of the word.